# How can I read my extension's version in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-2.0, version

In Magento 1.x I was able to read my module's version like so:

```
(string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/MyModuleName/version');
```

I'm unable to figure out how I can do the same in Magento 2.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could inject Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface in to your module helper class and then have a helper function to get it. Something like;

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    const MODULE_NAME = 'xxx';

    protected $_moduleList;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ModuleListInterface $moduleList)
    {
        $this->_moduleList = $moduleList;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->_moduleList
            ->getOne(self::MODULE_NAME)['setup_version'];
    }
}
```

Sorry, i haven't had time to put this in to code and test it thoroughly.

Comment: setup version is not the extension version but db schema version, it is not one from composer.json

Answer (score 8):

Try following way:

```
$moduleInfo =  $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList')->getOne('SR_Learning'); // SR_Learning is module name

print_r($moduleInfo);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [name] => SR_Learning [setup_version] => 2.0.0 [sequence] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if i understood your question completely, but you could use `n98-magerun2` and then export the result:

```
n98-magerun2 dev:module:list
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bit different but not that hard.

All you have to do is inject the `\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface` via helper constructor and use that in custom function.

Here is the full working code taken from https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints

```
<?php
namespace MagePsycho\Easypathhints\Helper;

/**
 * Utility Helper
 *
 * @category   MagePsycho
 * @package    MagePsycho_Easypathhints
 * @author     Raj KB <magepsycho@gmail.com>
 * @website    http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface
     */
    protected $_moduleList;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList
    ) {
        $this->_moduleList              = $moduleList;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }



    public function getExtensionVersion()
    {
        $moduleCode = 'MagePsycho_Easypathhints'; #Edit here with your Namespace_Module
        $moduleInfo = $this->_moduleList->getOne($moduleCode);
        return $moduleInfo['setup_version'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers retrieve the **setup version** of the extension.
Use code below for getting the **composer version** of the extension.

**Case 1.** We'll get version from composer.json file from extension directory

```
class VersionFinder
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Utility\Files $files
    ) {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        $pathToNeededModule = '';

        $composerFilePaths = array_keys(
            $this->files->getComposerFiles(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE)
        );

        foreach ($composerFilePaths as $path) {

            //from app/code - may be specific logic
            if (strpos($path, 'MageWorx/Downloads/composer.json')) {
                $pathToNeededModule = $path;
                break;
            }

            //from vendor - may be specific logic
            if (strpos($path, 'mageworx/module-downloads/composer.json')) {
                $pathToNeededModule = $path;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($pathToNeededModule) {
            $content = file_get_contents($pathToNeededModule);

            if ($content) {
                $jsonContent = json_decode($content, true);

                if (!empty($jsonContent['version'])) {
                    return $jsonContent['version'];
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Case 2.** We'll get the extension's version from [composer.lock](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies) file.
In this case we can get only the versions for extensions which were installed using composer installation. If you find the composer **metapackage** version - choose this case also.

```
class ComposerVersionFinder
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation
     */
    private $composerInformation;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation $composerInformation       
    ) {
        $this->composerInformation = $composerInformation;
    }

    public function getVersion()
    {
        $data = $this->composerInformation->getInstalledMagentoPackages();

        if (!empty($data['mageworx/module-customergroupprices']['version'])) {
            var_dump($data['mageworx/module-customergroupprices']['version']);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

P.S.  The code is executed slowly and I don't advise using this code in the frontend area. I supposed you need it on own extension page in the admin area.