# Will the installed third party plugins upgrade when we upgrade Magento version via composer

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

Currently, our Magento store running with the version Magento 2.2.3. We have upgraded the Magento version to Magento 2.2.6 via composer.

We would like to know that the installed third-party plugins will upgrade automatically when we upgrade the Magento version via Composer?

Please reply with your sweet answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Its only upgrade magento core files which exist in **vendor** folder.

You have to get upgraded modules to make them compatible with **magento 2.2.6.**

Comment: Thanks. Also, I want to know that Is it possible to check the versions of all the third party plugins which I have installed using the command? Or Do I need to check each and every module manually?

Comment: ok Please check here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99529/how-can-i-read-my-extensions-version-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Do upgrade through

```
composer update
```

This will automatically update which third-party plugins installed via composer(see composer.js). The other ones inside app/code/Vendor cannot be upgrade new version through this. You'd need to manually upgrade by downloading and upload follow their third-party instructions.